# Property doesn't match type of instance variable?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, pointers, properties

I took some sample code from [Apple's SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html)

Which looks like this:

```
@interface PutController () <UITextFieldDelegate, NSStreamDelegate>
...
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) uint8_t *buffer;
...
@end

@implementation PutController
{
    uint8_t _buffer[kSendBufferSize];
}
...
@end
```

But when I copy it to my code I get an error:

```
Type of property 'buffer' ('uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *')) does not match type of instance variable '_buffer' ('unsigned char [32768]')
```

My code is exactly the same as their sample, and yet it won't compile. What's going on here?

Comment: Here's a tip for formatting markdown - avoid `<br>`'s like the plague, use `<pre>` for outputs, and always give titles for links. It makes posts much more pleasant to read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, while arrays can decay to pointers, with clang, at least, it doesn't auto-decay into a readonly pointer when used in a property.

The simplest way to fix this is by having a second instance variable which is simply a pointer to the first element into the array, and have your property synthesize to that, like this:

```
@interface MyObj : NSObject

@property (readonly) uint8_t *buffer;

@end

@implementation MyObj {
    uint8_t *_bufferPtr;
    uint8_t _buffer[1024];
}

@synthesize buffer = _bufferPtr;

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _bufferPtr = &_buffer[0];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Alternativey, simply implement your own getter implementation to simply return the pointer to the first element of `buffer`. It's your call, really.

It isn't optimal, but it does appear to work the way you want.

Comment: Richard, Thanks for your response, but I just want to know why the sample is compiling and mine is not.  Code in both projects are the same. They are not synthesizing or two separate vars. I will probably use your code until I get an answer. Once again, thanks.

Comment: @user1054503 compiler differences I'd wager that the sample code you downloaded is being compiled with GCC (which probably allows this) whilst the new project is using the newer clang compiler. It's possible it's a bug, but you'd have to dig through language specs to be sure.

Comment: I looked at Build Settings and both are using Apple LLVM compiler 4.2

Comment: @user1054503 I just downloaded their example, and sure enough, they have a custom getter, which overrides the settings for @synthesize. Look at the `- (uint8_t *)buffer` method.